# Finding out keywords in javascript from a paragraph of text

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

How can I take keywords from an input e.g (`textarea`, `text`,...) in JavaScript and then store that keyword in an `array` of `string` that the length of words are greater than or equal to seven  let me show you an example I have the following paragraph in HTML:

```
<html>
 ...
   <body>
          <textarea id="keyword" cols="10" rows="20" placeholder="write content here"></textarea>
   </body>
 </html>
```

and I fill the `textarea` with the following content:
  **The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database.**
and then I want to store the keywords in JavaScript for instance:

```
<javascript>
       var keywords = ['Eloquent', 'included', 'provides', 'Laravel','beautiful', 'ActiveRecord', 'implementation', 'working', 'database'];
</javascript>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: How is javascript (or PHP maybe ?) supposed to know which word is a key word ?

Comment: What do you mean with keywords? Are those keywords predefined?

Comment: You either need a list of keyword or a list of useless word to do so

Comment: @Dawlatzai I mean you need to define it by yourself first, neither PHP or JS or any language can define it for you also it might be either to do it backward and just having an array of useless words like "The","That" etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try POSTagging.

This might point you in the right direction https://github.com/dariusk/pos-js

What I would do, is determine the Part of Speech for all of these and then run through the list and add into an array which ones are Nouns and Adjectives.

It won't be perfect but it'll be a start. Here's a code example

```
var pos = require('pos');
var words = new pos.Lexer().lex('The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database');
var tagger = new pos.Tagger();
var taggedWords = tagger.tag(words);
var output=[];
for (i in taggedWords) {
    var taggedWord = taggedWords[i];
    var word = taggedWord[0];
    var tag = taggedWord[1];
    //check if tag is a noun or adjective
    if(tag.indexOf('NN')==0 || tag.indexOf('JJ')==0)
       output.push(word)
}
console.log(output)
```

My output of this was

```
[ 'Eloquent',
'ORM',
'Laravel',
'beautiful',
'simple',
'ActiveRecord',
'implementation',
'database' ]
```

Basically, only simple turned up too

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are trying to create is not possible, because if you look out any informative sentence, then you will find billions of keywords like this. Javascript or PHP language has no clue of whether these are special words, its just us humans who see these as keywords. So, for this problem, you might want to define the array yourself.

*There can be one way. You can check each word of the paragraph, and if the first letter is a capital letter, then you might want to store that(because most of your keywords begin with a capital letter). Work out the code for this logic.